# How to get big \{ and \} braces for an equation

Tags: delimiters

How to type big `\{` and `\}` braces in this sentence:

```
$$P_{n,k}=\{\{x,y\}\in [X]^2: n=\min \{m\in
\omega: B_m(x)\cap B_m(y)=\emptyset\}; (x,y)\notin G_k\}$$
```

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Hi John, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I edited your question by using the `{}` button.

Comment: You can also do \left\{ and \right\}

Comment: @cmhughes - Good one, about using the `{}` button to edit a question involving `{` and `}`...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For your particular equation, using `\left\{` and `\right\}` to get larger curly braces won't do you much good, as the material being encased by the braces isn't much taller than a parenthesis. Hence, I suggest you use `\bigl\{` and `\bigr\}` for the inner set of braces (the stuff following `\min`), and `\Bigl\{` and `\Bigr\}` for the outer set:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ P_{n,k} = \Bigl\{ \{x,y\} \in [X]^2: n= \min 
\bigl\{ m\in\omega : B_m(x) \cap B_m(y)=\emptyset \bigr\} ; 
(x,y) \notin G_k \Bigr\} \]
\end{document}
```

Incidentally, the use `$$ ... $$` to generate display-math equations is heavily deprecated. It's much safer to use `\[` and `\]` (as I do in the example above). For much more on this subject, please see [Why is `\[` ... `\]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001)